# How does the swapping from uppercase to lowecase and vice-versa works with this regex?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript: Input a string and converts upper case letters to lower and vice versa

```
swapcase = function swapcase(str) { 
  return str.replace(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)/g,
    function(match, chr) { 
      return chr ? match.toUpperCase() : match.toLowerCase(); 
  });
}
console.log(swapcase('AaBbc'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`/(a-z)+|(A-Z)+/`
```

- `(a-z)+` - Match any lowercase character one or more time. (Capturing group 1)
- `|` - Alternation same as logical OR
- `(A-Z)+`- Match any upperCasecase character one or more time. (Capturing group 2)

JS [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method has following strcture

`str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)`

Here this function takes [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) as `(match, group1,group2..., offset,string)`

```js
const swapcase = function swapcase(str) {
  return str.replace(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)/g, function(match, chr) { 
      return chr ? match.toUpperCase() : match.toLowerCase(); });
} 

console.log(swapcase('AaBbc'))
```

So in your code `chr` is group 1. which matches lowercase characters only. and in your return your swapping case based on value of `chr`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you explanation.